# How to mention a range in the where clause of a query?

Tags: android, sqlite

How to mention a range in WHERE clause of a query. i.e for example: if i have a table with two columns 
1.name
2.experience

and now if a want all the names of people who have experience from 5 yrs to 10 yrs . what should i do. how do i write a query in android for this?

Comment: where experience in("whatever your argument set  is").

Comment: use raw query... Just type actual sql query. it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use BETWEEN clause in SELECT Query..

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT name FROM table_name WHERE experience < 10 AND experience > 5;`

Answer (score 1):

it is very easy..
do like this..

> SELECT (name) FROM table_name WHERE experience BETWEEN 5
>   AND 10